# How can I schedule a Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I used to be able to do it from hangouts.google.com but it looks like Google removed the feature from there.

I don't think the feature is gone because I still have a working link from a Hangout I scheduled a few months ago.

I think Google just hid the schedule feature. Any idea how I can get it back?

Answer (score 3):

You do it through Google Calendar now. Add your participants and tick "Include Hangouts" in the Google Calendar app for Android, or "Add video call" from creating an event in `calendar.google.com`.

[image: "Add video call" link in Google Calendar]